# How to change wallpaper on portable Telegram for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, telegram-messenger

I have recently installed Telegram on my iPhone and the portable version of Telegram (v1.8.8) on my Windows 7 laptop. While I've been able to change the wallpaper on my phone (Settings | Appearance | Chat Background), I can't work out how to do this on my laptop. So at the moment the wallpaper is full of flowers, and if it were any more girly it would have pink heart shapes all over the place. How can I change this? I click on the three line icon and then on Settings and can't find a way to change the background.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer now. It's to click on the three lines and then go Settings | Chat Settings | Chat Background.